# Python Error Message: time data '0' does not match format '%S.%f' (match)

Tags: python, datetime, milliseconds

I am trying to convert a series of float64 to datetime as I intend to resample the data later. The dataframe looks like this:[image]

I tried the code below:

```
# 'C_Time' doesn't include year-month-day-hour-minute information
df['C_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C_Time'],format = '%S.%f')

# Resample data into 200ms frequency
df.set_index('C_Time', inplace=True)
df = df.resample('ms').interpolate().resample('200ms').asfreq().dropna()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

but received this error message:

> ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%S.%f' (match)

I suspect that it's because the %S format requires an extra 0 before the ones digit (i.e. the C_Time should be 00.000, 00.094, 00.250) for this to work, but I'm not sure. Is there an easier way to convert this column into datetime?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it because python's 0.000 float is stored as 0?

Comment: the error tells you exactly that you have a value `'0'` in the series you're trying to parse. you have to filter that first, or just use `pd.to_datetime(df['C_Time'], format='%S.%f', errors='coerce')` to get NaTs for those values.

Comment: I see. But if errors='coerce' were used, the entire column would become pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType. I need this column to be of type datetime to perform resample(). I'd also like to keep the first 0 because it represents the beginning of the experiment.

Comment: Hm maybe it would be better then to parse the col to float, then add it as a timedelta in seconds to a reference timestamp. Not sure if resampling would work with pure timedelta.